# Users lookup in chat search breaks with JavaScript error

Tags: bug, status-planned, chat, chat-search

When using the [chat search](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search) and trying to filter by user, I get this after typing several letters:

> [image]

Two letters work fine, third or fourth letter breaks the lookup.

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: chat room box is also affected

Comment: @alexolut yeah probably same code breaks behind the scenes. :(

Answer (score 3):

Turns out this is *similar* to the bug described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302680/undefined-site-for-chat-room/302693#302693): the N which is the "unexpected token" is the N in "No records." again. But now instead of messing up the formatting a bit, it's just throwing an exception.

The bigger issue here isn't so much the error as it is the non-functional autocomplete. This is caused by that same old autocomplete plugin trying to cache the results of the last search - but expecting those results to be in a simple pipe-separated list format, when in fact each result is JSON. Thus rendered unable to match anything in its cache, it resorts yet again to the default `noRecord` value and hands it off to the formatter - which *was* expecting JSON, and grouses about tokens.

Once again, providing a sensible default for `noRecord` would be nice here. But a more important fix would be providing a parser for the JSON, and thus allowing the cache to work. Alternately, disabling caching would allow it to continue working at the cost of a few more server requests.

TL;DR: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Can't you work your JS magic to fix it yourself?

Comment: Probably, but that's not really my goal in writing this. I've probably researched this at least three times over the past year or so, and keep forgetting what's going on - the actual fix is trivial, but of course there are a bunch of different places it needs to be applied... So I'd rather document this once and save having to remember why it's happening in the future.