# Undefined site for chat room

Tags: bug, status-planned, chat

I just tried to [create a chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) and wanted to change the related site. Accidentally I typed `1` and saw an item named "undefined" with broken icon:

> [image: Undefined site]

Selecting this item shows "No records." message in the field for a short amount of time. Related site remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

This is the outcome for *any* input that doesn't produce a match. That pop-up uses an ancient (pre jQueryUI) jQuery Autocomplete plugin, recently updated to [this fork](https://github.com/agarzola/jQueryAutocompletePlugin) which has a few updates for support of modern browsers and jQuery versions. But as far as I can tell, this isn't a new bug; it probably behaved in this way for as long as that site selector has been active.

One of the not-particularly-well-documented (or, one might argue, thought out) features of that plugin has to do with what happens if no results match. There's an option named `noRecord` which defaults to the string `"No Records."` - this gets passed to the same formatter that normally expects (and gets) an object containing the properties "SiteCaption" and "SiteIcon", and which generates that image + description you'd see for each site in the list. It would appear that, in JavaScript, by default, the string "No Records." has neither property.

And so we get an undefined icon and an undefined description and, if selected, the value "No Records." for an instant until the pop-up is removed from the screen. Naturally, the site isn't changed as there's no site with the domain "No Records."

A fix for this, should anyone care enough to make one, would probably involve setting the `noRecord` option to something a bit more descriptive than "No Records." and then testing against that new value when considering whether or not to render a match or accept a result.

Comment: "should anyone care enough to make one" - you can...

Comment: Nope. Above my pay grade. I just document bugs, sort of a house entomologist if you will.

Comment: I see. Well, really too minor a bug to matter anyway. :)