# Error while trying to hide undefined community

Tags: bug, status-completed, hidden-communities

On the [hidden communities page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/wtf) when the list of visible communities contains more than 12 sites the search bar has appeared:

> [image: something]

If you entered something that doesn’t coincide with your visible community you will see “undefined” in results. Selecting this item enables “add to...” button and changes the text to “No Records.”:

> [image: addto]

Pushing the button leads to error message:

> [image: error]

This behavior looks same as for selecting a site in chat: [Undefined site for chat room](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302680/339911)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed.

I've actually run into this problem in the past with an internal autocomplete that would show "No Records." on complex expressions and then wipe out your text if you clicked it.  We were using two versions of an old unmaintained library.  One was used on any page that had tag autocomplete and the other was used a handful of other places, like the community picker.

For whatever reason, the non-tag version has a feature where it displays a selectable "No Records." item when there are no matches which actually inserts the text "No Records." on select.  The reason it shows "undefined" is because we pass a rebuilt array of objects into the function and display `row.name` but when there are no rows, `row == "No Records."` and `"No Records.".name == undefined`.  There's a whole can of worms with the options I used trying to fix this, but I won't go into that because...

I deleted that version of the library and am instead using the one bundled with tag autocomplete everywhere on the site.  That version actually solves this problem and has been maintained internally over the years, so it's best to just get everything in one place.

Comment: When the next build will be implemented?

Comment: @alexolut It just ran. The changes are now live.